# How do I get this code in Racket to return only the non-repeating items?

Tags: scheme, racket

The code works like this, I pass several lists and it returns me all lists in just one. What I want it to do is that after joining the elements in a list, it removes the repeating elements. To be clearer:

The code is working like this:

```
> (koo '(p x k c l) '(l x y c) '(x k))
'(p x k c l l x y c x k)
```

I want him to come back to me like this:

```
> (koo  '(p x k c l) '(l x y c) '(x k))
'(p y )
```

Here the code:

```
(define (koo  . c)
   (if (null? c)
       empty
       (concatenate1 (first c)
                    (apply xor* (rest c)))))

(define (concatenate1 l1 l2)
   (if (null? l1)
       l2
       (cons (first l1) (concatenate1 (rest l1) l2))))
```

Comment: Write a function that counts all the repetitions of list items. Then return just the ones whose count is 1.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how to join with this function

Comment: `(remove-duplicates (xor* ...))`

Comment: It's totally independent of this code.

Answer (score 0):

A not very efficient version using just basic `racket` functions:

```lisp
(define (unique-elements lst)
   (let ((dup (check-duplicates lst)))
        (if dup
            (unique-elements (remove* (list dup) lst))
            lst)))

(define (xor* . lol) (unique-elements (append* lol)))
```

Looks for the first duplicate element, and if any, removes all instances of that element from the list, and repeat until there are no duplicates.

- [Documentation for `check-duplicates`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._check-duplicates%29%29).
- [Documentation for `remove*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%2A%29%29)
- [Documentation for `append*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append%2A%29%29)